# Use JQuery variable as OFFSET in SQL query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to implement an infinite scroll functionality for posts in a news feed. The posts are loaded into the news feed as soon as the user reaches the footer.

---

**The Problem**
 **Every time the ajax call is executed I would like to increase the offset of the query**. I want to transfer the jquery offset variable somehow to php and the SQL query.

---

**The Code**

```
// Infinite Scroll
var offset = 0;
if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.post-wrapper').offset().top + $('.post-wrapper').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
    if (element_in_scroll("footer")) {
        $('div.loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?= Config::get('URL'); ?>index/loadPosts',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data) {
                    $(".post-wrapper").append(data);
                    $('div.loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                    offset++;
                } else {
                    $('div.loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>Es sind keine weiteren Posts vorhanden.</center>');
               }
           }
       });
   }
});
```

**The Query**

```
$query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 1 OFFSET $offset");
$query->execute();

return $query->fetchAll();
```

---

The offset increments as I would like it to, in the jquery code (`console.log(offset)` ouputs 1, 2, 3 and so on...). However, I cannot get this variable into the SQL query.

I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending javascript variable `offset` in your ajax request

Change following line:

```
url: '<?= Config::get('URL'); ?>index/loadPosts',
```

to:

```
url: '<?= Config::get('URL'); ?>index/loadPosts?offset=' + offset,
```

Prevent SQL injections:

```
$query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 1 OFFSET :offset");
$query->execute(array(':offset' => $offset));

return $query->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? What am I not doing exactly? Sorry, I am really new to this.

Comment: Then bind the `$_GET['offset']` to the query. Not like what you are doing now because that would allow for SQL injections. There is no point in preparing if you leave your SQL open like that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Pass the `offset` value in `AJAX`.
2. `GET` the `offset` value in your `PHP` file

   ```
   // Infinite Scroll
   var offset = 0;
   if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.post-wrapper').offset().top + $('.post-wrapper').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
   if (element_in_scroll("footer")) {
       $('div.loadmoreajaxloader').show();
       $.ajax({
           url: '<?= Config::get('URL'); ?>index/loadPosts?offset='+offset,
           success: function(data) {
               if(data) {
                   $(".post-wrapper").append(data);
                   $('div.loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                   offset++;
               } else {
                   $('div.loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>Es sind keine weiteren Posts vorhanden.</center>');
              }
          }
      });
   }
   }
   ```

**In PHP File**

```
$offset = $_GET['offset'];
$query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 1 OFFSET $offset");
$query->execute();

return $query->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It works perfectly!! However, I accepted Aamirs' answer, since he was faster.

Comment: Np, We all are here to help :)